# incorrect view size ios

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am using UIViewController for display my view. My view have been created in interface builder.

Right now these are next parameters for view:

width: 568
height: 320
Orientation: Landscape

in ViewController I have next code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

in info.plist I have added just two interface orientation right and left.

but when I try to output width of my view in code I get 320 and when I try to output height it write down in console 568 but I expect 320 instead.

I don't know why it works like this. Any suggestions?

even if I add this:

`[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 320)];` in viewDidLoad method. even then I have inccorect height

I need to know width size I use in this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat width = 0.0f;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        width = 568.0f;
    } else {
        width = 1024.0f;
    }    
    NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / width;
    NSLog(@"%d", page);
}
```

Right now I use hardcode variable of width, but how come. Why I can't use `self.view.frame.size.width` because the sides swop each other - because.

Comment: Let me inform you about the existence of the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` macro, much more readable.

Comment: Can you paste the code you're using to print the width of the view, as well as at what point in the view life-cycle this code is executing (load, willappear, didappear, way after...)

Comment: NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height); I need to calculate in UIScrollView deleagte scrollViewDidEndDecelerating

Comment: What is your view's autoresizing mask set to?

Comment: ha, one thing that I saw right now it is next:
I out my value in viewDidLoad NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.width); and get 568 how I expect, but when I scroll my UIScrollView and call scrollViewDidEndDecelerating method I got another value 320. how come ? :)

Comment: and without any changes with frame in source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're printing width and height in the viewDidLoad method before the orientation occurs. Try to print it on viewWillAppear or with performSelector:afterDelay:

Another thing that might affect the dimension of the view is how you set the autoresizing mask on the interface builder (the red arrows below the x,y,height,width section on the right panel)

Comment: yeah i have played with this but no changes

Answer (score 0):

Please add `LaunchScreen.storyboard` in your project and set it as your Launch Screen under

> Targets > General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen file.